# Сравнение больших нетекстовых файлов

Tags: c#

Есть некоторые файлы, которые программа должна сравнивать(они будут далеко не всегда текстовые), причем они могут быть большого размера, так что побайтовое сравнение тут скорее всего использовать нельзя, ибо скорость должна быть нормальной.

Мне нужно проверять файлы на то, равны они или нет, не нужно искать все расхождения.

Подскажите хорошие решения, или хотябы в какою сторону смотреть.

Comment: Вам как сравнивать? На равенство или искать все расхождения? Ну и тупое сравнение байт в байт, я подозреваю, будет наилучшим по скорости.

Comment: Сравнить хэши этих файлов?

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk это будет однозначно медленнее побайтового сравнения

Comment: Чтобы вычислить хеш, нужно прочитать все байты файла, потому проще уж сравнить сами файлы побайтово

Comment: Без развернутого объяснения фразы "сравнивать файлы" ответ дать нельзя. Вам нужно узнать, чем отличаются файлы, или просто проверить, идентичны ли файлы байт-в-байт?

Comment: главное, при реализации побайтового сравнения не читать файлы с диска побайтово.

Comment: Можно добавить предварительные операции. Например, простое сравнение размеров файлов покажет большинство разных пар ещё на подлёте.

Для больших файлов одинакового размера можно заморочиться, например, так: разбить на куски заданных размеров, и сравнивать пары кусков параллельно.
Ну и да - сравнивать побайтово, предварительно прочитав в память целиком :)

Comment: @eastwing , можно подробнее про разбиение на куски и их сравнение? Желательно сразу ответом.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как отметили в комментариях, побайтовое сравнение будет самым быстрым (если все байты в памяти, конечно - впрочем, в C# реализовать обратное надо ещё умудриться).

Но для начала файлы можно просто сравнить по размеру. Если он разный - очевидно, файлы отличаются.

Если размеры идентичны, и нужно всё же сравнивать побайтово, файлы можно разбить на куски, и запустить сравнение в параллельном режиме.

Приведу код с примером такого сравнения. Код не идеальный и не универсальный, но вы сможет от него оттолкнуться

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileCompare
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Считываем файлы в память
            var file1 = File.ReadAllBytes("file1.bin"); //10 000 000 байт
            var file2 = File.ReadAllBytes("file2.bin"); //10 000 000 байт

            var partsCount = 10; //количество частей
            var partSize = 1000000; //размер части

            //делим файлы на списки частей
            var parts1 = new List<IEnumerable<byte>>();
            var parts2 = new List<IEnumerable<byte>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < partsCount; i++)
            {
                var skip =  i * partSize;
                parts1.Add(file1.Skip(skip).Take(partSize));
                parts2.Add(file2.Skip(skip).Take(partSize));
            }

            //Создаём список тасков. Метод Task.Run запускает задачу сразу после создания
            //Так же обратите внимание на current = i в каждой итерации.
            var comparsionTasks = new Task<bool>[partsCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < partsCount; i++)
            {
                var current = i;
                comparsionTasks[current] = Task.Run(()=> 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Running {current}...");
                    return parts1[current].SequenceEqual(parts2[current]);
                });
            }
            //ожидаем завершения всех задач
            Task.WaitAll(comparsionTasks);

            //вывод результатов в консоль
            foreach (var task in comparsionTasks)
                Console.WriteLine(task.Result);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Кстати, учтите, что для небольших файлов это решение только замедлит сравнение. Тут только замерять.

И ещё: можно использовать [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) для того, чтобы останавливать сравнение как только обнаружены разные байты.

Comment: Читать сразу все содержимое файла с диска - не очень хорошая идея, особенно если шанс что файлы различаются - достаточно высок.

Comment: Распараллеливание не нужно. И вообще, какая-то жесть с чтением в память и выдиранием кусков через linq. Скорее всего, это наоборот получится очень медленно.

Comment: Неужели в шарпе нельзя читать поблочно (скажем по 64К)? И неужели в винде (где в основном пишут на шарпе) в ядре не реализовано опережающее чтение? Если на оба вопроса ответ отрицательный, то оптимальный алгоритм очевиден.

Answer (score 3):

Конечно предложенный лобовой вариант правильный, но неэффективный. Проще таки вычислять и сравнивать хэши файлов (например md5). Поскольку уже давно не писал под C# напишу некий псевдокод:

```
 boolean identical=true;
 byte[] buffer;
 while(!file1.eof() && identical) {
    file1.read(buffer1);
    file2.read(buffer2);
    hash1=hashFunction(buffer1);
    hash2=hashFunction(buffer1);
    if(hash1!=hash2)
       identical=false;
 }
```

Коллеги, более сведущие в C# легко переведут его в нормальный код.

**Update**

По результатам дискуссии предлагается изменить псевдокод, для каждого файла вычисляем хэш его контента:

```
 byte[] buffer;
 hash=null;
 while(!file.eof()) {
    file.read(buffer1);
    hash=hashFunction(buffer+hash);
 }
```

Далее при сравнении файлов, если длины файлов одинаковы можно уже просто сравнивать заранее сохраненные значения хэшей.

Предпочтительно использование хэш функции типа SHA-512, который гарантирует наименьшую вероятность коллизий.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь сказать, что сравнить два байта - медленнее, чем посчитать MD5 от одного байта?

Comment: хэш вообще то считается от массива байтов...

Comment: Хэш можно посчитать и от одного байта, как это ни странно.

Comment: Да, можно, если с головой не дружить - одной из функций хэша как раз и является укороченное представление большого массива данных :)

Comment: Функцией хэша является получение различных (!) результатов для различных данных, а уж укорочение - исключительно побочный эффект, который к тому же проявляется далеко не всегда, что очевидно.

Comment: Коллизии конечно возможны, но таки первичная функция именно укороченное представление, кому как не вам это знать - вы же типа *криптограф* :)

Comment: Я-то как раз не "типа", поэтому и утверждаю, что укорочение - эффект побочный и не всегда проявляющийся. И что хэшировать через MD5/SHAn можно любой объем данных, а уж кратный байту - и подавно.

Comment: Ну это из серии: что было сначала яйцо или курица. Не будете же вы отрицать, что хэширование таки в основном используется для укорочения больших массивов данных - в частности ЭЦП, как одно из важных следствий или использование хэша для индексации? Ну а ваш экскурс на тему вычисления хэша для одного байта оставим в стороне, и так ведь ясно, что идеальным хэшем для байта является сам байт :)

Comment: Barmaley ок, простой пример - вы сравниваете два 10Gb файла, отличающиеся первым байтом. Сколько данных будет прочитано с диска при сравнении подсчетом хэша, и сколько - при побайтовом сравнении до первого несовпадения?

Comment: @PashaPash пример явно некорректный, речь то шла о том, чтобы не сравнивать все байты (как предлагается), а сравнивать только хэши

Comment: @Barmaley ну так подсчет хэша - не бесплатен. смотрите, сравнивается два файла, размером N. Если файлы одинаковые - то это 2N чтений на подсчет хэшей + 2N на побайтовое сравнение. Если разные - то 2N чтений на подсчет хэшей. Побайтовое сравнение - 2N если одинаковые, <<2N если разные

Comment: Вы как сговорились что ли? Где я говорил, что собираюсь вычислять хэши каждого байта? Специально для таких догадливых поправил псевдокод

Comment: причем тут подсчет хэшей для каждого байта? вы считаете один хэш для N-байтового массива. это чтение N байт.

Comment: дописал мессагу выше :)

Comment: Почитайте [эту дискуссию](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19659/comparing-files-is-it-better-to-use-multiple-hash-algorithms-or-just-one) в soCrypto - мнения разделились, но таки большинство настаивает именно на сравнении хэшей, а не на побайтовом сравнении

Comment: даже в вашем примере - сколько он чтений делает из памяти? hashFunction(buffer1) == N + hashFunction(buffer1) == N. + еще придется делать 2N если хэши одинаковые.

Comment: да, там в "дискуссии" бред написан. "I think you are misunderstanding how a hash works though. It does not read bits and pieces of the file, it processes the whole thing into a small output which is a "signature" of that file" - ну да, подсчет хэша не требует чтения файла, как же. И даже в этом ответе "But, **it is not by itself any faster than comparing piecewise whether two files are equal**"

Comment: подсчет хэшей имеет смысл если файлов больше двух. потому что тогда он реально экономит повторные чтения одного и того же файла при сравнениях его с другими.

Comment: @PashaPash там есть и другие суждения :)

Comment: @PashaPash к тому же вы неверно поняли приведенную ваму сентенцию :)

Comment: ок. вы можете обосновать, почему сравнение через посчет хэшей выгоднее? без отсылки к сомнительному обсуждению, где самая заплюсованна вещь - это коммент "Byte-for-byte comparison is faster than MD5 or CRC, unless you don't want to upload whole file and you compute hash on client's computer."? :)

Comment: *подсчет хэшей имеет смысл если файлов больше двух. потому что тогда он реально экономит повторные чтения одного и того же файла при сравнениях его с другими.* - золотые слова, а теперь перечтите вопрос ТС...

Comment: перечитал. да, круто. если ваш ответ приложить к вопросу топикастера - он не поможет. т.к. ваш псевдокод считает хэш при *каждом попарном* сравнении. напишите, что хэш надо запоминать вне попарного сравнения, что при совпадении хэшей все равно надо сравнивать побайтово - и ответ будет хорошим. а сейчас - это что-то вроде "вредных советов" :)

Comment: @Barmaley, в вопросе нигде не говорится, что будет сравниваться больше 2 файлов одновременно. А при сравнении хэшей возможен неверный результат из-за коллизий. По-хорошему, в случае, если сравнение хэшей дало ответ, что файлы одинаковые, надо по ним ещё раз пройтись и сравнить побайтово.

Comment: Обновил ответ. Все покидаю, чат - всем  спасибо