# Можно ли как-то проверить файла на копию другого файла?

Tags: c#, файлы, uwp

Есть два файла, один является копией другого , и у них разные имена но имена не важно так как они могут быть одинаковые , как правильно проверить является ли один копией , пробовал через сравнивание ReadBytesAsync , но возвращает false при сравнивании. Использую StorageFile/StorageFolder.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358510/how-to-compare-2-files-fast-using-net Там есть код как для побайтового сравнения (очень медленно для больших файлов), так и для сверки по контрольным суммам.

Comment: У нас тут есть похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743761/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2 Но на английском ответы расписаны лучше.

Comment: Копия имеется в виду бинарная? А то ведь текстовые файлы с содержимым `A` и `a` можно считать одинаковыми.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю, как там в UWP, но вот накатал пример для сравнивания простым фрейморком. Идея простая как гвоздь - сраниваем имя файлоа, потом размер, потом контент.

```
public class FileEqualsChecker
{
    public async Task<bool> IsSameFile(string fname1, string fname2)
    {
        if (string.CompareOrdinal(fname1, fname2) == 0) return true;
        if (!IsSameSize(fname1, fname2)) return false;
        return await IsSameContent(fname1, fname2);
    }

    private bool IsSameSize(string fname1, string fname2)
    {
        var finfo1 = new FileInfo(fname1);
        var finfo2 = new FileInfo(fname2);
        return finfo1.Length == finfo2.Length;
    }
```

размер блока 1 мегабайт, можете менять как вам надо

```
    private const int BLOCK_SIZE = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    private async Task<bool> IsSameContent(string fname1, string fname2)
    {
        var block1 = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
        var block2 = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];

        using (var sr1 = CreateStream(fname1))
        using (var sr2 = CreateStream(fname2))
        {
            int l1 = 0, l2 = 0;
            do
            {
                l1 = await sr1.ReadAsync(block1, 0, block1.Length);
                l2 = await sr2.ReadAsync(block2, 0, block2.Length);

                if (l1 != l2) return false;
                for (int i = 0; i < l1; i++)
                    if (block1[i] != block2[i]) return false;   

            } while (l1 > 0 && l2 > 0);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

читаем с буфером в 10 мегабайт.
Выбирайте размер буфера по своему желанию

```
    private const int BUFFER_SIZE = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    private Stream CreateStream(string fname) =>
        new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fname), BUFFER_SIZE);  
}
```

Проверка

```
var f1 = @"D:\temp\data.sql"; // 90 мб
var f2 = @"D:\temp\data - Copy.sql";  // 90 мб
var f3 = @"D:\temp\data3.sql";  // 20 мб
var f4 = @"D:\temp\Database.sdf";  // 200 мб

var checker = new FileEqualsChecker();

Console.WriteLine($"{f1} {f2} = {await checker.IsSameFile(f1, f2)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{f2} {f3} = {await checker.IsSameFile(f2, f3)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{f3} {f4} = {await checker.IsSameFile(f3, f4)}");
Console.WriteLine($"{f4} {f4} = {await checker.IsSameFile(f4, f4)}");
```

Вывод

```
D:\temp\data.sql D:\temp\data - Copy.sql = True
D:\temp\data - Copy.sql D:\temp\data3.sql = False
D:\temp\data3.sql D:\temp\Database.sdf = False
D:\temp\Database.sdf D:\temp\Database.sdf = True
```